# TestNG: Is it possible to break test Suites to run single parallel test Suites

Tags: maven, parallel-processing, testng

I have a little doubt on the my work around. Let me please, Explain my work. I have the following structure of my test:

BeforeSuite
tests
aftersuites

these are in different suites and I don't need to run multiple times  before and after suites.But "tests" should be run in different browsers. so it is a kind of series parallel(sorry if it is not the good word) concept.
I would like to create single testNG suite that run:
beforesuite first of all then 
tests in all browser(ie, chrome,firefox) in one computer(not used remote driver yet.)
aftersuites at the end only one driver. I am working like this:

```
    <suite-file path="testforChrome"/>
    <suite-file path="testforFirefox"/> 
    <suite-file path="testforIE"/> 
    <suite-file path="beforeSuite"/>
    <suite-file path="AfterSuite"/>

</suite-files>
```

but I don't have any luck yet.
Do someone have some idea please?

Comment: Your question is still not clear. It would be good if you could please elaborate a bit more with some examples maybe.

Comment: for example, I have already created test suites, one is run before suite, another test suites and another after suites.  Basically, I designed only to test on one browser and it works as expected. But Now, company wants to run in all browsers. So, what I want is run before suites first in only one browser, when it completes, then run test suites for all browsers and after run aftersuite test in only one browser.
I cannot Run before after suite testsuite more than once because, they will created multiple instances and my test will fail. and after suites is clean up function.